# Swift 3: Convenience Initializer Extending Foundation's 'Timer' Hangs

Tags: swift, timer, swift3, initializer, convenience-methods

I am attempting to extend Foundation's `Timer` class in Swift 3, adding a convenience initializer.  But its call to the Foundation-provided initializer never returns.

The problem is illustrated in the following trivialized demo, which can be run as a Playground.

```
import Foundation

extension Timer {
    convenience init(target: Any) {
        print("Next statement never returns")
        self.init(timeInterval: 1.0,
                  target: target,
                  selector: #selector(Target.fire),
                  userInfo: nil,
                  repeats: true)
        print("This never executes")
    }
}

class Target {
    @objc func fire(_ timer: Timer) {
    }
}

let target = Target()
let timer = Timer(target: target)
```

Console output:

```
Next statement never returns
```

To study further,

• I wrote similar code extending `URLProtocol` (one of the only other Foundation classes with an instance initializer).  Result: No problem.

• To eliminate the Objective-C stuff as a possible cause, I changed the wrapped initializer to `init(timeInterval:repeats:block:)` method and provided a Swift closure.  Result: Same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't actually know the answer, but I see from running this in an actual app with a debugger that there's an infinite recursion (hence the hang). I *suspect* that this is because you're not in fact calling a designated initializer of Timer. This fact is not obvious, but if you try to subclass Timer and call `super.init(timeInterval...)` the compiler complains, and also there is an odd "not inherited" marking on `super.init(timeInterval...)` in the header.

I was able to work around the issue by calling `self.init(fireAt:...)` instead:

```
extension Timer {
    convenience init(target: Any) {
        print("Next statement never returns") // but it does
        self.init(fireAt: Date(), interval: 1, target: target, 
            selector: #selector(Target.fire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        print("This never executes") // but it does
    }
}
```

Make of that what you will...

Comment: The "not inherited" marking in the header is to state that it cannot be used as an initialiser for a subclass, due to the fact that it's imported from an Obj-C factory method (`timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`) which only returns `NSTimer` instances (thus cannot be used to create a subclass instance). Although I don't see why this should make it infinitely recurse (cannot reproduce with my own Obj-C factory method), therefore it's probably something in the `NSTimer` implementation doing it. Most peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

I see the same issue as described by matt with infinite recursion. `-[NSCFTimer release]` is called over and over on the same object. This behavior can be reproduced in pure Objective-C by calling a class initializer from within an instance initializer.

```
@implementation NSTimer (Foo)

- (instancetype)initWithTarget:(id)t {
    return [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:t selector:@selector(description) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

@end
```

The compiler complains that a designated initializer isn't being called which very well seems related to fixing the issue but doesn't explain the recursive calls.

```
warning: convenience initializer missing a 'self' call to another initializer
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @matt works.

Yes, I saw that infinite recursion in my app, too – CFReleases.  The Swift book is clear that **convenience initializers must call designated initializers**.  It doesn't say what the penalty is, though.  An infinite recursion, though surprising, is plausible.

However, look at these two declarations which you can see by option-clicking or command-clicking on one of these methods in Xcode:

```
init(timeInterval interval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void)

convenience init(fire date: Date, interval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void)
```

I think something is wrong there.  The function @matt suggested, with the additional ("fire") parameter, which solves the problem for me, is marked *convenience*.  The function I used, which is **not** marked *convenience*, I presume (as a Swift newbie) is therefore *designated*.  But it has one less parameter.  Huh?

I think I shall file a bug stating that **Apple somehow got the *convenience* keyword on the wrong function**.  This may be possible because Swift really doesn't have header files, correct?  So I wonder what we're seeing when we option-click on a Foundation function.  Possibly there is a step in their workflow which is susceptible to human error?

Comment: The Swift book says **Rule2: A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.** and **Rule3: A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.** The rules does not inhibit a convenience initializer calling another convenience initializer of the same class. And in other classes, defining a convenience initializer which calls another convenience initializer actually works. So, you should send a Bug Report with the original issue. `Timer` is a special case. How generated headers are shown is a subtle thing and would be ignore.

Comment: You are correct, @OOPer.  All initializers should *eventually* call a designated initializer, so as long as my convenience initializer calls another initializer, designated or not, it should work.

Comment: I've now filed **Apple Bug Reporter Problem ID 29804952** on the original issue.  In *Additional Notes* I asked how function X has one less parameter than function Y, but function Y is the one marked *convenience*.  Thank you all.